# Jquery delay is not working after hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with jQuery delay. I need to add a class after 5 seconds, so I wrote this:

Working example:

```
$('#category #product_list .ajax_block_product').on('mouseover',function(){
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        that.find('.sl').show();
        that.find('.product_img_link img').hide();
        that.addClass('hovered');
    }, 500);
});

$('#category #product_list .ajax_block_product').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('.sl').hide();
    $(this).find('.product_img_link img').show();
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

It is working on the first time, but when I hover a second time, the `hovered` class is not added and I do not know why.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: `500` milliseconds is not 5 seconds, you want `5000`

Comment: First this surrounded by '' is it ok?

Comment: yes it is surounded by '' should I use ""?

Comment: @folpy What about `$(this)` instead of `$("this")`?

Comment: Why do you surround first this and don't do same for next this? Any purpose?

Comment: Class is not added second time because it is still there. I don't see any statement for removing it after the whole hover process.

Comment: Try to use only this, without any '

Comment: There is second part: $('#category #product_list .ajax_block_product').on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(this).find('.sl').hide();
  $(this).find('.product_img_link img').show();
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
 });

Comment: `$('this')` is not the this you thought 'this' was.

Comment: just use `setTimeout(function(){...}, 500);` instead of `$('this').delay(500).queue(function() {...`

Comment: sorry but setTimeout is not working I edit current code in first post

Comment: Some idea why setTimeout is not working?

Comment: because, `$(this)` doesn't work inside of `setTimeout`.

Comment: write `var that = $(this);` outside of `setTimeout`, then use `that.find...` inside of `setTimeout`

Comment: when I delete this from setTimeout it start working thanks for help

Comment: I answer below. you can accept it

Comment: also, `clearTimeout` is important thing here

Answer (score 0):

Try to use;

```
var tm;
$('#category #product_list .ajax_block_product').on('mouseover',function(){
    var that = $(this);
    tm = setTimeout(function(){
        that.find('.sl').show();
        that.find('.product_img_link img').hide();
        that.addClass('hovered');
    }, 500);
});

$('#category #product_list .ajax_block_product').on('mouseleave',function(){
    clearTimeout(tm);
    that.find('.sl').hide();
    that.find('.product_img_link img').show();
    that.removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the 500 to 5000, as mentioned in the comments. 100 = 100ms (millisecond), not 1 second. 1 second = 1000ms.

Comment: 100 = 100ms. 1000 = 1000ms = 1s.